# GridView Template Field (How to deal with DropDown list Selected Item)

Tags: asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I have employee registeration page with DropDownList control (Occupation). I am storing Occupatrion.SelectedValue in the Database when new Employee is added.

I have GridView implemented on FindEmployee page where information from the Employee Table (Database) table is bound.

I am using Template field in the GridView and trying to retrieve value of Occupation. But it is showing selected value i/o SelectedItem (Yes i know why it is showing value i/o item)

My question here is how can i show Occupation select item using template field?

Any Idea please

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `DropDownList.Text` property which actually set the `DropDownList.SelectedValue` property and causes the corresponding `ListItem` to be set as selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the OnRowDataBound event in your code behind and set the value there as follows:

```
 If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

   Dim ddl as DropDownList =  CType(e.Controls.Find("id_of_the_drop_down"), DropDownList)  
   ddl.FindItemByValue("YourEmployeeOccupation").Selected=True
 End If
```

Warning: I'm not a VB guy, so I'm not 100% sure about my syntax above but that's the idea.